# Haskell: Convert input string directly to list

Tags: string, list, haskell

Is there any way to convert an input string directly to a list?

The input string is already in the form of a list e.g.:

```
[((1,2),x),((3,2),y)]
```

I just want to convert it to `[((1,2),x),((3,2),y)]` which can be used in another function without having to through the string to get all the values and then make an identical list.

Is this possible?

Comment: What are `x` and `y`?

Comment: Are you asking for `read`?

Comment: x and y are types i have definced myself.

Read is only for converting a string of numbers to int isn't it?

Comment: Your input string references variable names?

Comment: The input string is in form [((Int,Int), Animal)] where Animal = Dog | Cat, so no references to variable names, only type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to define a `Read` instance for your type.

```
> data Animal = Dog | Cat deriving (Read, Show)
> read "[((1,2),Dog),((3,2),Cat)]" :: [((Int, Int), Animal)]
[((1,2),Dog),((3,2),Cat)]
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked perfectly! Hours of googling, yet the solution is so simple... Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned, you can use `read` to convert your `String` into a value of type `[((Int, Int), Animal)]`, provided `Animal` is an instance of `Read`. The instance can be derived automatically:

```
data Animal = Dog | Cat deriving (Show, Read)
```

Another potential pitfall is that you should specify the type annotation explicitly so `read` knows what to parse for:

```
main :: IO ()
main =
    do let list = read "[((1,2),Dog),((3,2),Cat)]" :: [((Int, Int), Animal)]
        animals = map snd list
    print animals
```

The output:

```
$ runhaskell test.hs
[Dog,Cat]
```

Comment: Thanks! Should I specify the type annotation even if it works, or is it mostly for safety/prevents errors in the future?

Comment: Look at the type of `read`: `read :: Read a => String -> a`. If you constrain the type variable `a` so that it is completely unambiguous (by using the result of `read` in a context which makes the type clear), then the compiler will know which `Read` instances to use and you won't need to add an annotation. In other cases, like my code above, it'll complain that a type variable is ambiguous.